# Regarding the synchronized function

Tags: java

I was interviewed and I was asked about a class with two functions m1() and m2(). m1() is synchronized and m2() is not and two threads t1 and t2 are in trying to access this object. Now if t1 is accessing the m1() function, then can t2 access the m2() method at the same time?

I said *yes* it should be allowed to access it as there is no lock on m2() method, but the interviewer insisted that as the lock is on the same object it will not allowed to access the m2() function to t2 thread.

For this I wrote a program to check and found that whatever I was saying was right. Please see the program with the output.

```
class myExperiment2 implements Runnable{
    myThreadEx m;

    myExperiment2(myThreadEx m){
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            m.m2();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class myExperiment1 implements Runnable{
    myThreadEx m;

    myExperiment1(myThreadEx m){
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            m.m1();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class myThreadEx{

    synchronized void m1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("1 am in m1....1");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("I am in m1()");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("1 am in m1....2");
    }

    void m2() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("1 am in m2....1");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("i am in m2()");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("1 am in m2....2");
    }
}

public class ThreadEx {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        myThreadEx m = new myThreadEx();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new myExperiment1(m));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new myExperiment2(m));

        t1.start();
        t2.start(); 
    }
}
```

The output is

> 1 am in m1....1
>   1 am in m2....1
>   i am in m2()
>   1 am in m2....2
>   I am in m1()
>   1 am in m1....2

Can some one suggest me if I am missing something or if there is possible scenario where I can be wrong and whatever interview was saying, was right?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, or you've not accurately related it, the interviewer was wrong.

Comment: @AndyTurner http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text Or try to explain why ___you___ think that printed text is code. I would love to know that.

Comment: @Tom output of programs (and things like stack traces) are best displayed in monospaced fonts because it preseves line breaks and spaces relevant to formatting. And it just looks nicer: the differing widths of the 1st column character messes with readability. And it's how it appears in your terminal when you run it (unless, shudder, you don't use a monospaced font in your terminal, which is simply daft).

Comment: @Tom note that your `linked meta question` is really talking about `gratuitous` use of inline code formatting to highlight words which aren't code; none of the answers are actually talking about blocks of code.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, or you've not accurately related it, the interviewer was wrong.

And, of course, given [the semantics of synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

```
synchronized void foo() { ... }
```

is identical to

```
void foo() { synchronized (this) { ... } }
```

(at least for an instance method)

Then other threads can always "access" the method at the same time (as in, multiple threads have that method in their stack trace); they just get blocked immediately.

Comment: And here come the part where you need to explain the interviewer that he is wrong. Some are open to the suggestion other are not.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that interviewer was wrong. He would have been right if both `m1` and `m2` were synchronized. In the case of your question, there was no lock associated with `m2`, therefore nothing stopping other threads from executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Interviewer was wrong unless he meant the following,

There are two type locking strategy you can adopt

1. Object's intrinsic lock (`this` like in your case or HashTable)
2. Private lock defined below

Private lock,

```
public class PrivateLock {
   private final Object myLock = new Object();
   @GuardedBy("myLock") Widget widget;

   void someMethod() {
      synchronized(myLock) {
           // Access or modify the state of widget
      }
   }
}
```

so if someone is doing following which will cause m2 to not invoke,

```
//myThreadEx also shared by another class which does myThreadEx.m1
synchronized(myThreadEx) {
    myThreadEx.m2(); 
}
```

Comment: Sure. I have fixed that.